# i have integrate between angular 6 and spring mvc. angular is client process and spring mvc be a server side working

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

i dont know how to connect client and server

client side running port:http://localhost:4200
server side running port:http://localhost:8082

Comment: Please clear your question. Not able to understand what you want exactly

Comment: how to connect front end and back end

Comment: client side code working in visual studio code and back end code working on eclipse. I need how to parameter passed to the back end.

Comment: your front end should make requests to http://localhost:8082 , also ensure CORS requests are enabled on server side